# Locked out of KDE while upgrading

Tags: upgrade, kde, lock-screen

In Kubuntu 17.04 in a terminal, I did `do-release-upgrade`. After the downloading was over, the unpacking, etc. began. I accidentally locked the screen. When I wanted to unlock, it displayed a message

> The screen locker is broken ... switch back to running session.

So I switched to virtual terminal, logged in and `loginctl unlock-sessions`. When I switch back using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd>, it still shows the same message.

When I tried `sudo shutdown -h now` it gave an error that update manager is inhibiting shutdown.

How do I get out of this mess? It has been more than 3 hours since this happened.

Comment: I would let it sit. If it goes another 3 hours you can try a hard reboot, but it the upgrade failed you may have to reinstall. Time will tell ...

Comment: @Panther I did as you suggested. And after about 4 hours, did `sudo shutdown -h now`. Everything went without an error and I could reboot into Kubuntu 17.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrades can take a long time and it is best to wait.

The message "update manager is inhibiting shutdown" suggests the upgrade is still in process and interrupting the upgrade, by forcing a shutdown, can break Ubuntu.

I suggest waiting , but if the problem persists in a few hours you can force a reboot, but doing so may cause problems, and in that event you would have to debug (can be difficult or impossible) reinstall (faster, more reliable).